# How long can PIC18 keep RAM after being powered off?

Tags: pic, ram

I've noticed unusual behavior from PIC18F4680.

I have declared following matrix: `char [7][5]` and I have function which loads the data into the matrix. Data is then read from the matrix and shown on two 5x7 displays.

During debugging, I've commented out the only call to the function which loads data into the matrix and after I reprogrammed the PIC, I was surprised to see that the shown image remained.

Just to make sure that there isn't some partially charger capacitor doing something strange, I shorted the power input and left it like that for maybe 5 minutes. After powering the board again, I've noticed that only 4 dots on the displays had wrong value.

So my question is: how long does it usually take for the RAM in PIC18 series to reset?

Comment: I think the question really boils down to: Does the PIC18 use SRAM or DRAM? DRAM could preserve it's state for a long period. SRAM is basically purged when it is depowered.

Comment: @Fake Name The datasheet claims that it uses SRAM.

Comment: Huh, well damn. I don't know what to tell you, then.

Comment: Are you controlling the displays with latched shift registers?

Comment: Did you shorten the power at the power pins of the PIC or somewhere at the power input of your board (maybe before the voltage regulator)? In the latter case there might be the possibility that there still remains some voltage enough to keep the SRAM from forgetting.

Comment: @m.Alin Yes, but I don't think that it could be them retaining the data. The registers are cleared very quickly and I'm using same clock for the latch and data input, so it couldn't be that the register latch kept the data.

Comment: @Curd I did it at the regulator. I'll try shortening pins directly now. Update: Shorting pins directly caused a bit nore corruption. Now six dots have wrong value.

Comment: @AndrejaKo "I'm using same clock for the latch and data input"  To save pins on the PIC?

Comment: @m.Alin Yes. The datasheet for the registers allows that.

Comment: I'm currently observing this behavior with an AT45DB041D, a DataFlash IC that has two RAM buffers. When I turn the board off for a minute or so, contents of these buffers are preserved. I haven't really tried to determine how long it takes for this IC to lose RAM data.

Comment: This would be an interesting topic for an automated test rig which measures the error probability over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PIC RAM is all CMOS static.  Apparently the capacitance saves the data sometimes for a while after powerdown, but this is by accident and nothing you can rely on.  It's not designed to work that way.

The only safe answer is that you have to assume all of RAM gets scrambled when Vdd goes below the minimum RAM retention voltage listed in the datasheet.  That is usually lower than the lowest operating Vdd, but I haven't looked it up for that PIC since this is something you can easily to yourself.

Comment: Actually I'm interested in the opposite. Is there any way to know when I can consider the data in the RAM to be lost?

Comment: @Andreja: Then you have to assume the answer is forever.  There is no guarantee when the capacitors will discharge enough to flip to the other state on powerup.  The only way to guarantee that RAM data is erased on power down is to explicitly clear it before powerdown.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I would expect that applying a small reverse current to the supply would likely greatly hasten the erasure without damaging the part.  Once VDD drops below about 0.6 volts, any nodes that are between (VSS-0.6) and (VDD+0.6) volts will effectively be floating, with nothing to charge or discharge them.  If VDD were driven negative just enough for parasitic and/or protection diodes to start conducting (but not so hard as to damage anything), all nodes that had been positive will have their value pegged to roughly (VDD+0.6).

Comment: If one was to intentionally use the retention as a best-efforts feature, checksumming could help :)